# Thunderbird search current folder only

Tags: search, thunderbird

In the new Mozilla Thunderbird email client, is it possible to search in the current folder only?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the folder and choose **Search...**

Answer (score 1):

Just use feature called Quick filter, it is activated by clicking icon near global search box, then lower search box appear which is for current folder only.

This is very fast and useful feature, only caveat that it sometimes switches off (eccidentelly press Escape), thus I created how to reactivate it with keyboard:
Press 'q' and just search!
Tho whole procedure is here
[How to configure Thunderbird Quick Filter toolbar shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/895130/how-to-configure-thunderbird-quick-filter-toolbar-shortcut/895131#895131)