# How to configure Thunderbird Quick Filter toolbar shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

In recent versions of Thunderbird, they changed behavior of Quick Filters search toolbar. I use it very heavily on thousands of mails. Now pressing Escape, will close it, and there is no quick way to re-enable it especially over RDP session with limited keyboard.

Question is how to make keyboard shortcut, example letter Q to quickly open and focus Quick Filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for Thunderbird 78 - the previously mentioned KeyConfig is not longer maintained - it stopped working well before TB 68.

Newer addon, tbkeys (specifically [tbkeys-lite](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/)) which does much of the same thing, perhaps more.  I use it now, having previously used KeyConfig.

Specific settings to accomplish the OP's request (and a few more):

```
    "/":            "cmd:cmd_showQuickFilterBar",
    "meta+f":       "cmd:cmd_showQuickFilterBar",
    "meta+ctrl+f":  "cmd:cmd_toggleQuickFilterBar",
    "meta+shift+f": "cmd:cmd_find",
    "ctrl+s":       "cmd:cmd_find",
    "meta+shift+s": "cmd:cmd_search",
```

GitRepo: [TBKeys](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys)

Comment: `cmd:cmd_toggleQuickFilterBar` doesn't seem to close the bar, though. Which can be done with ESC.

Answer (score 2):

The two steps are necessary.

1. Download and install Thunderbird extension [Keyconfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_customizing-keyboard-shortcuts)
2. Go to Addons, closk on Options near `keyconfig` addon and `Add new key`, name it Quick Filters, in command window put goDoCommand('cmd_showQuickFilterBar') and assign keyboard shortcut, for example Q.

That's it. Alternatively you can put command: `cmd_popQuickFilterBarStack` - to open Quick filter and clear any contents if there was, or even `cmd_toggleQuickFilterBar` which is self explanatory.